# Skip javadoc during compilation

Tags: java, netbeans, ant

I'm trying to build a Netbeans project (I'm not the primary developer) through the command line, using ant and it's failing in javadoc generation.

Is there any way to turn off javadoc during ant compilation?

Comment: What version of netbeans?

Comment: See if this will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5058086/how-do-i-exclude-a-specific-package-from-javadoc-in-netbeans

Comment: @JoopEggen Sorry for the confusion, see the edit.

Comment: Compilation does not include running Javadoc.Your question is unclear.

Comment: @EJP So what is running `ant build.xml` if not complication? I'm open to suggestions.

Comment: Do you mean 'compilation'? I'm not responsilble for what the targets in your `build.xml` do, but a `compile` target should not include a `javadoc` step.

Comment: @EJP Great, so how do I turn off javadoc generation? I can't modify the `build.xml`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generation of Javadoc can be skipped by explicitly invoking the build phase. Netbeans provide an internal label for this:

```
ant -f src_dir -Dnb.internal.action.name=build jar
```